# Copy Clipboard from iOS Simulator to Mac?

Tags: ios-simulator

Is it possible to copy clipboard from iOS simulator to my mac?

Not sure I should ask here or at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 29):

Using Xcode 10 Beta

Trying going to Edit>Automatically Sync Pasteboard. Mine was checked, but they weren't synced. Try unchecking it then re-checking it.

If that doesn't work, Uncheck it, select text and copy within simulator, then click Edit>Get Pasteboard.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Using the released Xcode 10.1 (not beta).

Comment: Our app calls `UIPasteboard.general.setValue(appViewModel.id,
                                                          forPasteboardType: "public.plain-text")`, which copies to the simulator's clipboard, but that value cannot be pasted into Mac. However, if you paste that value somewhere else in the simulator (like Safari's URL bar), then copy it *again* from there, the value now gets synced over to the Mac clipboard. No idea why, but this workaround is the only thing that works in our case.

Answer (score 22):

1. Select the text in the simulator, and make sure the edit menu with **"Copy"** is visible on the simulator screen
2. Use the Mac keyboard to press "**⌘ + C**" to copy the text into mac clipboard.

***Update**(Have tested on MacOS 11.3.1):*

1. Select the text in the simulator, and make sure the edit menu with **"Copy"** is visible on the simulator screen
2. Use the Mac keyboard to press "**⌘ + Shift + C**", and click **"Copy"** in the previous step to copy the text into mac clipboard

[image]

Comment: @Rendy  in Step 2, you need make sure select the simulator.

Comment: Saved my day!! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the use of the Edit Menu in Simulator.app to copy data between the macOS and iOS pasteboards, with Xcode 8, you can do this from the simctl command line.  Check out:

```
xcrun simctl pbinfo
xcrun simctl pbsync
xcrun simctl pbcopy
xcrun simctl pbpaste
```

Comment: Damn. This was surely the best answer!

Comment: Best answer, as it can be used in an automated script.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! First, make sure whatever you want to bring to the Mac is on your simulator's clipboard already. Then, do the regular copy shortcut (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) to bring the simulator's clipboard to your Mac's clipboard.

You should now be able to paste whatever it was on your Mac, given that it was a compatible format.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, neither in the latest released version of Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000), not in the beta.

Comment: Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me, I'm not sure why the simplest way isn't listed in one of the answers, but it is to first copy like you would usually on iOS, then browse to the simulator menu at the top left of MacOS: **Edit > Get Pasteboard**